# primefaces datatable rowexpansion with hidden column issue

Tags: primefaces, rowexpansion

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.0
I aim to create a data table with rowexpansion but I don't want to display rowtoggler. Expansion will occur on row selection. For this I have added to my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      rowExpansion(PF('carDataTable'));
   });

function rowExpansion(dataTable) {
      //dataTable should be the widgetVar object
      var $this = dataTable;
      $this.tbody.off('click.datatable-expansion', '> tr')
         .on('click.datatable-expansion', '> tr', null, function() {
            //toggle the current row the old toggler
            $this.toggleExpansion($(this).find('div.ui-row-toggler'));
          });
}
```

Rowtoggler column is hidden as:

```
<p:column style="display:none">
    <p:rowToggler />
</p:column>
```

The problem is that when row is expanded, the size of rows shrink. This also happens when any hidden column other than rowtoggler column exists. How it appears without expansion and with expansion is as follows:
[before expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUEsk.jpg)
[after expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Zks.jpg)

any workaround or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is good practice to create a [mcve] if you post something that is not working correctly. Then other who want to try to help have exactly the same code as you use. Please improve your question. Suggestion: Don't hide the column but just the things in it, or try making the column smaller and hide the right border or something. Or see what actually changes in the html/css when a rowis opened and try to correct that

Comment: Thank you Kukeltje. I had tried making the column smaller, but I could not. Then I realized that setting width alone is not sufficient. Setting padding and border together with padding solved my issue. <p:column style="width:0px;height:0px;padding:0px;border:0px">
     <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved with a workaround.
Instead of setting column property as `display:none`, hiding it by setting 0 size seems working.

```
<p:column style="width:0px;height:0px;padding:0px;border:0px">
    <p:rowToggler />
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update but now you can set the column visibility to false.

```
<p:column visible="false">
  <p:rowToggler/>
</p:column>
```